# Need example for independent random variables

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, random-variables

Let $(\Omega,S,P)$ be a probability space,and $X,Y$ be the random variables then $X$ and $Y$ are said to be independent if the sigma-algebra generated by $X$ say $\sigma(X)$ and sigma-algebra generated by $Y$ say $\sigma(Y)$ are independent.Also, let me define what is meant by sigma-algebra generated by a random variable ,we have $X:\Omega\to \mathbb{R}$ then  $\sigma(X)$={$A\subseteq\Omega $: $A=X^{-1}(B)$ for $B\in B(\mathbb{R})$} where $B(\mathbb{R})$ is a Borel sigma-algebra of $\mathbb{R}$.
My question: I understood the definition but I need one simple example to understand this definition of the independence of random variables.Thanks.

Comment: The simplest example is $X=1_A,Y=1_B$ where $P(A\cap B)=P(A)P(B)$.

Comment: Technically, the simplest example will have constant random variables...

Answer (score 0):

Instead of giving a specific example, I will try to give *many* examples, to hopefully build intuition. The example starts by removing the abstractions of our measurable space $(\Omega, S)$ and quantities $X, Y$. From there, we see which measures $P$ will induce our desired independence. Following this, I inspire the abstraction we have chosen.

#### Independent quantities on the product space.

Specifically let
$$(\Omega, S) = \big(\mathbb{R}^2, \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}^2)\big),$$
and $X, Y: \mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be the component maps.
$$ \begin{aligned}[b]
X(x,y) &= x, \\ Y(x, y) &= y,
\end{aligned} \quad (x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 $$
Independence of $\sigma(X)$ and $\sigma(Y)$ means we need to have the following identity.
$$ P(A_X \cap A_Y) = P(A_X) \cdot P(A_Y), \quad A_X \in \sigma(X), ~ A_Y \in \sigma(Y) \tag{1} $$
Under our specification, we see that our $\sigma$-algebras are the cylinder sets,
$$\begin{aligned} 
\sigma(X) &= \big\{ A \subseteq \mathbb{R}^2 : A = X^{-1}B \text{ for some } B \in \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}) \big\} \\
&= \big\{ B \times \mathbb{R} : B \in \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}) \big\} \\[1em]
\sigma(Y) &= \big\{ A \subseteq \mathbb{R}^2 : A = Y^{-1}B \text{ for some } B \in \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}) \big\} \\
&= \big\{ \mathbb{R} \times B : B \in \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}) \big\} \\[1em]
\end{aligned}$$
and so (1) now amounts to the following identity.
$$ P( B_X \times B_Y ) = P\big( (B_X \times \mathbb{R}) \cap (\mathbb{R} \times B_Y) \big) = P(B_X \times \mathbb{R}) \cdot P(\mathbb{R} \times B_Y) $$
This means that $P$ must evaluate the area $P(B_X \times B_Y)$ of a rectangle $B_X \times B_Y$ as the product of the width $P(B_X \times \mathbb{R})$ of $B_X$ and the length $P(\mathbb{R} \times B_Y)$ of $B_Y$.
More specifically, $P$ is a product measure of the distributions $P_X$ and $P_Y$, defined below.
$$ \begin{gathered}
P_X(B_X) = P(B_X \times \mathbb{R}) = P\big(X^{-1}B_X\big) \\
P_Y(B_Y) = P(\mathbb{R} \times B_Y) = P\big(Y^{-1}B_Y \big) \\
P(B_X \times B_Y) = P_X(B_Y) \cdot P_Y(B_Y)
\end{gathered} $$

#### Specific examples.

Basically choose two measures and [*Fubinate*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fubini%27s_theorem) them.
For example, choose $X$ and $Y$ to be distributed $\operatorname{Exp}(2)$ and $\operatorname{U}[0,1]$, respectively.
$$ \begin{aligned} P_X({\rm d}x) &= 1_{[0,\infty)}(x) 2e^{-2x} {\rm d}x, \\ P_Y({\rm d}y) &= 1_{[0,1]}(y) {\rm d}y \end{aligned}$$
Then impose our product.
$$ P(X \in A, Y \in B) = \int_A \int_B 1_{[0,1]}(y) 1_{[0,\infty)}(x) 2e^{-2x}  {\rm d}y{\rm d}x$$

#### An interpretation of this definition

Note that our algorithm for constructing measures above can generally be done.
Any time you have a measure space $(\Omega, S, P)$ and some $X: \Omega \rightarrow \mathbb{X}$ into some other measure space $(\mathbb{X}, \mathscr{X})$ that is $S/\mathscr{X}$ measurable, you have the $P$-distribution of $X$ on $(\mathbb{X}, \mathscr{X})$, denoted by $P_X$ and defined as such.
$$ P_X(B) = P\big(X^{-1}B\big), \quad B \in \mathscr{X} $$
Note that $P_X$ is somehow *coercing* $P$ to only evaluate *precisely* on $\sigma(X)$.
This way, independence of $\sigma$-algebras is always equivalent to factoring the joint distribution of $(X,Y)$ into a product of those of $X$ and $Y$ (as we did in our specific example above).
$$\begin{aligned}
&P(A_X \cap A_Y) = P(A_X)\cdot P(A_Y), & A_X \in \sigma(X), ~ A_Y \in \sigma(Y) \\[1em]
&\Leftrightarrow\quad P\big(X^{-1}B_X \cap Y^{-1}B_Y\big) = P\big(X^{-1}B_X\big) \cdot P\big(Y^{-1}B_Y\big) & B_X \in \mathscr{X}, ~ B_Y \in \mathscr{Y} \\[1em]
&\Leftrightarrow\quad P\big((X,Y)^{-1}(B_X \times B_Y)\big) = P\big(X^{-1}B_X\big) \cdot P\big(Y^{-1}B_Y\big) & B_X \in \mathscr{X}, ~ B_Y \in \mathscr{Y} \\[1em]
&\Leftrightarrow\quad P_{(X,Y)}\big(B_X \times B_Y\big) = P_X\big(B_X\big) \cdot P_Y\big(B_Y\big) & B_X \in \mathscr{X}, ~ B_Y \in \mathscr{Y} \\[1em]
&\Leftrightarrow\quad P_{(X,Y)} = P_X \otimes P_Y \text{ as measures on } \mathscr{X} \otimes \mathscr{Y}
\end{aligned}$$
The only difference in the general setting is that $X$ and $Y$ need not be component maps; how they evaluate points of $\Omega$ may not be so cleanly specified, and such is the importance of the $\sigma$-algebra formulation.